# Mapping abstract class, should common properties be mapped inside abstract or child class

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate

I have `ArticleBase` which is inherited by `ArticleComputer` and `ArticleCar`. I'm using nhibernate inheritance mapping with discriminator value. Everything is up and running but I have dilema, since ArticleBase has property `Tags` should I map this property inside `ArticleBaseMap` class or I should leave to child classes to map this common properties.

I guess it should be mapped inside abstract base class but I would like to hear from experienced user.

Thanks

Comment: The answer here is pretty simple: If this property is available on the ArticleBase Table (where the Discriminator column is) map it there. If this is related to child tables (e.g. ArticleComputer) then it belongs to child. So, **where the column is**... there in this case .. **should be the mapping** ;) Important: I am really not saying *where it is declared* (base, interface) ... but where it is persisted

Comment: so, if I'm understand correctly I should map inside child classes since every child article would always have tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer here is very straightforward:

- in case, that the property is available on the `ArticleBase` **Table** *(where the Discriminator column is)* **map it there**.
- if the column belongs to child table *(e.g. ArticleComputer)* then it belongs to the child maping.

So, **where the column is** there .. should **be the mapping**

It really does not mean: where it is declared *(base, interface)*. The reason could be, that in C# we do some common stuff in base implementation, while some children (for any reason) could not have this as a part of mapping *(it is just virtual)*

I.e.: We should **map** it where the column exists. Nothing else. And then, if we are about to **repeatedly** mapping it everywhere on all children *(because column is declared there)*:

.. change the design of DB. Move that from children back to parent table.